# What does it mean to say that a certain interval has an asymptotic coverage probability of 95%?

Tags: probability, statistics, confidence-interval

I'm not really sure how to define 'asymptotic coverage probability'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the limit of large data, $95\%$ of all cases will fall within the interval.

Think of a binomial distribution.  With just a *few* points, you might get errant few points outside the interval, greater than $5\%$.  But when you have some large number of points (e.g., $10^9$ points), then a version of the law of large numbers states $95\%$ (or whatever) will lie in the relevant interval.